# What is the meaning of ${*.version} for a dependency in a Maven POM file?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In a `pom.xml` file, I see something like this. What is the meaning of `<version>${SomeProject.version}</version>` here? Is it to tell Maven to use the latest version of that dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.some.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>SomeProject</artifactId>
    <version>${SomeProject.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The version is defined by property, see: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-user-defined-properties-in-maven/

Comment: Got it :) Maybe you can put it as an answer.

Comment: This is a property. You can find custom-defined properties in your pom.xml under `<properties>` tag. Your `<version>` tag will get injected by the value defined in the `<properties>`